# Delete multiple rows in Android SQLITE

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

In my app, I am trying to execute two delete queries at the same time, which delete using same input. I am using IN clause. But I am getting an error. My key is a String value.

Method....

```
public void deleteUsingList(String[] ids) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_FAV_AMEN, KEY_AD_ID + " IN (" + "?)", ids);
    db.delete(TABLE_FAV_HEAD, KEY_AD_ID + " IN (" + "?)", ids);
    db.close();
}
```

My error....

```
2019-04-14 19:57:48.102 14802-14802/com.estate.dushanmadushanka.estate E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.estate.dushanmadushanka.estate, PID: 14802
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Too many bind arguments.  2 arguments were provided but the statement needs 1 arguments.
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.delete(SQLiteDatabase.java)
        at com.estate.dushanmadushanka.estate.other.SQLiteHandler.deleteUsingList(SQLiteHandler.java:159)
        at com.estate.dushanmadushanka.estate.activity.FavouriteActivity$2.onClick(FavouriteActivity.java:84)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "CAST("+KEY_ID+" AS TEXT) IN (" + new String(new char[ids.length-1]).replace("\0", "?,") + "?)", ids);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass parameters to the `IN` clause like this. 
 
I suppose `ids` is a `String` array of the ids you want to delete. 
You must create a string consisting of all the items of the array `ids` delimited with `,`:

```
String strIn = TextUtils.join(",", ids);
```

you will need this import:

```
import android.text.TextUtils;
```

and then:

```
db.delete(TABLE_FAV_AMEN, KEY_AD_ID + " IN (?)", strIn);
```

This will work if the ids are integers, but if they are strings you have to enclose them all in single quotes first.

Comment: ids are Strings